# OctoberCMS Get URL to CMS page

Tags: redirect, twig, octobercms

In October CMS, you can easily create a link to a CMS page in a Twig template with [reverse routing](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-page#reverse-routing). For example:

```
<a href="{{ 'help'|page }}">Go to help page</a>
```

will link to the CMS page with the filename `help.htm`, substituting the URL with the URL defined in that page.

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the URL to a CMS page in a component to create a redirect to it.

I tried:

```
return Redirect::to('help');
```

which simply redirects to `/help` URL, which isn't the correct URL, so I get a 404.

I also tried:

```
return Redirect::to(\Url::route('help'));
```

However this produces an error because it is not registered as a route.

The reason I can't just hard-code the URL is because I am using the [Translate](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate) plugin, which means that I can have a different URL depending on the language. So for example, in English it would be `/en/help`, but in Spanish it would be `/es/ayuda`. Putting:

```
{{ 'help'|page }}
```

in my Twig files will automatically get the correct URL based on the current language.

Is this possible to do in a component or controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your component you can use `controller's pageUrl` method.

```php
$this->controller->pageUrl(<file_name>, <params>);
```

> according to your need, this should do the trick

```php
return Redirect::to($this->controller->pageUrl('help'));
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. You are very knowledgeable.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I am glade it helped you :)